# Trying to settle on a database model for words and translations?

Tags: django, database

So right now my model looks like this...

```
class Language()
    name= Char()

class Word
    id = pk()
    language = ForeignKey(language)
    name = Char()

class Translation()
    original = FoeignKey(word)
    L2 = ForiegnKey(language)
    definition = Text()
    translation = Char()
```

The problem I have with this is that say I have two languages (English/Spanish) and two words (el/la, the). With my current model I would have to have two translation objects for these two words.

```
class Language()
    name= Char()

class Word
    id = pk()
    language = ForeignKey(language)
    name = Char()

class Translation()
    language1 = FoeignKey(word)
    language2 = ForiegnKey(word)
    definition_language1 = Text()
    definition_language2 = Text()
```

Although I tried to do option 2 and I think it wouldn't let me directly have to ForeignKeys to the word class.

I think I have thought myself into a corner, and I can't decide if it is totally necessary to do option 2 or not. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't what you have more of the structure where you have a Word table, a Language table, and then your translation table is a through table connecting the Word table with itself. Then you can put all that additional information on the through table, and query it as a connection between two Word objects

If you don't know what a through table is, the documentation for how to use it can be found here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships

Answer (score 0):

Why not use your second example with a `related_name`?

```
class Translation()
        language1 = ForeignKey(word, related_name = 'masculine')
        language2 = ForeignKey(word, related_name = 'feminine')
```